# onsubmit function wont fire while having a runat=server attribute

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">


</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">

<br />

<div id="signupform">

<form  class="signupform" name="formreg" runat="server" onsubmit="return valform()"> <br/>

<input dir="rtl" type="text" name="uname" class="uname"/> </br>

<input dir="rtl" type="text" name="fname" class="fname"/> </br>

<input dir="rtl" type="text" name="lname" class="lname"/> </br>

<input dir="rtl" type="password" name="pword" class="pword"/> </br>

<input dir="rtl" type="password" name="rpword" class="rpword"/> </br>

<input dir="rtl" type="text" name="mmail" class="mail"/> </br>

<input dir="rtl" type="text" name="rmail" class="rmail"/> </br>

<input dir="rtl" type="text" name="gil" class="gil"/> </br>

<input type="checkbox" name="anon" value="True" class="dropan"/></br>

<input type="submit" name="sub" class="subbutton" value=""/>

<%=registrationstatus %>
</form>

</div>

</asp:Content>
```

This is my code, My problem is that the onsubmit="return valform()" attribute on my form wont fire if the runat="server" attribute exists, they can't work together please help me I am clueless why these two attributes wont work together

Comment: When a form is `runat="server"` it sets the `onsubmit` attribute with the `javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();` value and apparently it overrides the value you are setting. What are you trying to do with the `valform()` function?

Comment: Yes, please show us the    valform() function.

Comment: Do you have another form declared on the master page as well?

Comment: Yes I do, but it isn't running on the server

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't use both together. As said in the docs -

```
<input type="text" id="Textbox1" runat="server">
```

> Doing this will give you programmatic access to the HTML element on the server before the Web page is created and sent down to the client. The HTML element must contain an id attribute. This attribute serves as an identity for the element and enables you to program to elements by their specific IDs. In addition to this attribute, the HTML element must contain runat="server". This tells the processing server that the  tag is processed on the server and is not to be considered a traditional HTML element.

Here is the reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478973.aspx
under section - **Using HTML Server Controls**

So, HTML with `run='server'` will not be treated as a normal Html element and thus will always be processed by the server. If you want to override the default behavior, you have to bind your javascripts with after the html is loaded in the browser, may be using jQuery or something similar. With jQuery something like this would help -

```
$(function(){
    $("#formreg").submit(function(){
        return valform();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By examing your code, I reach on conclusion that you might be using another form tag on Master page and there is no javascript issue. Only one form tag(Server Side) can exists either on a master page or content page. They can not be nested. When you would use runat="Server" attribute on both of form tags then error occurs saying `"A page can have only one server-side Form tag"`. So remove `runat="server"` attribute from one of the form tags, `onsubmit` would begin firing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with very easy way.

if we have such a form

```
<form method="post" name="setting-form" >
   <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" value="" 
      placeholder="user name" >
   <input type="password" id="Password" name="password" value="" placeholder="password" >
   <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
    <label>remember me</label>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" />
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="login" id="login-btn"/>
</form>
```

You can now catch get that event before the form postback and stop it from  postback and do all the ajax you want using this jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#login-btn").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("do what ever you want");
            });
 });
```